# Curve modifier around bezier circle in Blender 3.0 not functioning correctly

Tags: error, versions, curve-modifier

Weird one. Im deforming a very simple cubic plane around a bezier circle using the 'Curve' modifier.
Problem is when the bezier points of the circle are moved at all, I get this hard twist in the geometry halfway around.

It only appeared since I updated to 3.0. The original file was made in 2.8 and when opening back in either 2.8 or 2.9 it works fine - just broken in 3.0.

It also happens when creating a completely fresh file and starting from scratch. See shot.

[image: Blender3 curve error]

Any ideas?

Edit:
Adding the super basic file setup that has the error. Does the same thing happen when anyone else opens it?
https://www.mediafire.com/file/5zmy8hxr48s6953/CurveMod.blend/file

Comment: hello, could you please share your object (upload and copy paste the URL)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hey there. Popped a link in the main body, heres one using your file share too :)
https://pasteall.org/blend/4a78522f62e8415b982897d5d2b009cf

Answer (score 3):

Just move in edit mode your plane to 0. Then it works:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks Chris. Why on earth would that be the solution? Given that in previous versions of Blender it didnt work that way. What's changed??

Comment: I don’t know and I didn’t try the older versions. Since I work with Blender it was always that way ‍♂️